# TFS 2013 - API User Setup

Tags: api, tfs

We have TFS 2013 setup on our own server in house. We have about 8 windows users from AD that currently use it.

I need to interact with TFS via API from a console app that will run on a different server. I have it all working fine when running as my own Windows account. How can I set up a user in TFS that will be used only for API interaction? I searched around and it seems I can't add a non-Windows user to TFS for this. Is it possible to use a service account or something? What is the best practice for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did that different server which running a console app  in the same domain with your TFS server?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not any API related service account. You could take a look at this thread:  [**Service Accounts for Team Foundation Server**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/service-accounts-dependencies-tfs#service-accounts-for-team-foundation-server)
Which include a table shows all the service accounts that you might use in a deployment of TFS such as TFSService, TFSBuild...

As a workaround, you could create a public domain account in TFS used for API related. However it's not able to restrict the account only used for API interaction. Since for which permissions are needed for an end user/domain user to call into the TFS  API, this is **based on the action that you request through TFS API**. For example if your TFS API is used for checking in files, API account need code related permission, used for triggering a build, then the API account need build related permission. More information of permission, please refer to: [Permission reference for Team Foundation Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/permissions)